# Question about instantiating object

Tags: objective-c

I am new to Objective C and Cocoa. Really don't like the syntax as I'm from Java and C#. I'm trying to do something simple and I get the following error:

I import this in using

```
#import "Defaults.h"

-(void) awakeFromNib{
            Defaults *theDefaults = [[Defaults alloc] init];
}

-(IBAction) addPlanets:(id)sender{

[theDefaults setValue:[planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem] forKey:@"planets"];
NSLog([planetsButton titleOfSelectedItem]);
}
```

The error I get is

Unknown Receiver theDefaults; Did you mean "Defaults"?

Can someone help me on what this is?

Answer (score 5):

`theDefaults` doesn't exist in the scope of `addPlanets:`.  You need to make it a global or an instance variable, rather than creating it in `awakeFromNib` and immediately leaking it.

Comment: This is the case in Java and C# as well, by the way. Local variables do not magically seep through method boundaries.