# Accessing objects for in an array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsstring

I have an array set up like:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Item 1", @"Item 2", @"Item 3", @"Item 4", @"Item 5", nil];
```

And I would like to access the contents of the array to display them in an NSString but I am unsure what to use, for example:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [objectAtIndex:0]];
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [objectAtIndex:1]];
```

But my array is declared in `- (void)viewDidLoad` and I need to access them in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` - How would I access them  and display them in an NSString?

Comment: You have to make `array` an instance var. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851963/question-about-instantiating-object/6852037#6852037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the array an instance variable.  Then you can access it from any instance method.

Comment: And what would the second part be? Would [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", [objectAtIndex:1]; be correct to access each object?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to answer the second part: Use the %@ format with [array objectAtIndex:idx].